# Can't connect instance that is migrated to AWS

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, azure, virtual-machines, migration

I am migrating Azure instance to AWS, I migrated it successfully but when using EC2 instance connect or doing SSH using key pair I am unable to login. How can I resolve this issue?

Steps I Followed

1. Created Snapshot of Azure Disk
2. Downloaded the snapshot '.VHD' (30GB)
3. Uploaded file to S3
4. Created snapshot using ec2_client.import_snapshot

```
ec2_client.import_snapshot(
        DiskContainer = {
                'Description': 'DiskContainers Description',
                'Format': f'{file_format}',
                "UserBucket": {
                    'S3Bucket' : f'{s3_bucket}',
                    'S3Key' : f'{s3_key}'
                }
            }
    )
```

5. Created Image(AMI) using ec2_client.register_image

```
ec2_client.register_image(
        Architecture = 'x86_64',
        BlockDeviceMappings=[
            {
                'DeviceName': '/dev/sda1',
                'Ebs': {
                    'DeleteOnTermination': True,
                    'Iops': 3000,
                    'SnapshotId': f'{snapshot_id}',
                    'VolumeSize': volume_size,
                    'VolumeType': 'gp3',
                    'Throughput': 125,
                }
            },
        ],
        Description='A description for the new image',
        DryRun = False,
        EnaSupport=True,
        Name=f'{ami_name}',
        RootDeviceName='/dev/sda1',
        VirtualizationType='hvm',
        BootMode='uefi'
    )
```

6. Created Instance from AMI using ec2_client.run_instances

```
ec2_client.run_instances(
        ImageId=ami_id,
        InstanceType=instance_type,
        KeyName=key_pair_name,
        MinCount=1,  
        MaxCount=1,
        SecurityGroupIds=security_group_ids
    )
```

Images 
[Status Check Fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0sl8.png) 
[Failed Status Check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJ9vT.png) 
[Ec2 instance connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWPdm.png) 
[Ec2 SSH (The azure_key is and AWS generated key pair)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHuq0.png)

Comment: That's an unusual way to migrate a VM to AWS. Suggest you use the recommended method, AWS Application Migration Service, which despite its name actually migrates VMs.

Comment: @Tim Thank you sir for your feedback but I wanted to do it using code, I am developing a project using python

Comment: Interested if you get this working. I suspect the application migration service makes some changes to images as they're imported to let them run on AWS, this method would avoid that. Given this is quite unusual you would probably be best off asking AWS Support, which is available for a fee.

Comment: Can you connect using the console and check your authorized keys file? Did you import your ssh key into aws and then deployed the VM?